# How to make a div fixed

Tags: html, css

I have this kind of HTML code :

```html
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <div>
            <input id="myinput" type="text">  
            <table>
               <tr style="display: none;" >
                  <td>
                     hidden row 1
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr style="display: none;" >
                  <td>
                     hidden row 2
                  </td>
               </tr>
               <tr style="display: none;" >
                  <td>
                     hidden row 3
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </div>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         I want you to stay fixed
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

When I unhide hidden rows programmatically  the last row (I want you to stay fixed) moves down, I want that row not to move down. I'm unhiding at most 3 rows in real code as well. So how can I modify my code so, that row would not move. Thanks.

Comment: What have you researched and tried to far? SO isn't really a "how to" site.

Comment: "_I want that row not to move down_". No? How would you want them to move then? They must move, if you're adding rows before/after existing rows ...

Comment: And how exactly do you want the hidden rows to display after you unhide them? Should they be below the "i want to stay fixed" text?

Comment: @MateuszJuruś They need to appear above "I want to stay fixed"

Comment: @Teemu Is it impossible to create a buffer space so that text wouldn't move?

Comment: @Teemu Or is it impossible to make table with buffer space?

Comment: You can hide the rows using `visibility` property instead of `display`, that would be a "display buffer".

Comment: @Teemu If I have 200 rows in real code, will that mean I will have 200 rows of buffer?

Comment: Yep, if you don't want that, you most likely need a script to scroll the page so, that a specific row would seemingly keep its place. That question would be too broad to answer without your own attempt, though.

Comment: Isn't really there a way to make a row fixed where at most three rows appear above once in a while? I think there must be a way for that..

Comment: Sorry, it's row..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited your code try this one

```
<style>
#myiput{
position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}
</style>
    <table>
       <tr>
          <td>
             <div>
                <input id="myinput" type="text">  
                <table>
                   <tr style="display: none;" >
                      <td>
                         hidden row 1
                      </td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr style="display: none;" >
                      <td>
                         hidden row 2
                      </td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr style="display: none;" >
                      <td>
                         hidden row 3
                      </td>
                   </tr>
                </table>
             </div>
          </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>
             I want you to stay fixed
          </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using CSS visibility property to do so.

```
div.style.visibility="visible";
```

I hope it is useful to you.

[Here is my sample code](https://jsfiddle.net/3ejosL1j/3/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that creates extra spaces as I wrote in comments.

Comment: That is what @Teemu states "display buffer".

Comment: But it looks too ugly when there are hundreds of rows.

Comment: That is the current limitation.
You have 2 choices only, 
1. Use display (But the content of each row expand)
2. Use visibility (But it spare a space for each content)